# IntelliJ Java Editor Color Scheme

Tags: java, intellij-idea

How do I change this light grey background color behind the "public" (see screenshot) ?

Screenshot:

http://i.picresize.com/images/2016/03/24/X6B3Q.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using Google once in a while, or take a look at the IntelliJ Docs

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/configuring-colors-and-fonts.html?origin=old_help